# Minio replication issues

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, minio

when adding a replication rule to my GUI in minio the replication rule works. I have deleted the replication rule to add a new one to the same host and another bucket.

But when trying to add the new rule I get the error: 'The remote target already exists'.
To debug this I connected with the terminal, when using the command `mc replicate ls` I get the error: 'Unable to list replication configuration: replication configuration not set.'.

I have seen that the mirror function has a --overwrite function, is there also a function that looks like --overwrite to use with replicate?

How can I fix this error because I need to replicate my minio to another s3.